# How to create a function to tell whether a value is increasing or decreasing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe

I want to create comments from a dataset that details the growth rate, market share, etc for various markets and products. The dataset is in the form of a `pd.DataFrame()`. I would like the comment to include keywords like increase/decrease based on the calculations, for example, if 2020 Jan has sale of 1000, and 2021 Jan has a sale of 1600, then it will necessary mean an **increase** of 60%.

I defined a function outside as such and I would like to seek if this method is too clumsy, if so, how should I improve on it.

```
GrowthIncDec = namedtuple('gr_tuple', ['annual_growth_rate', 'quarterly_growth_rate'])

def increase_decrease(annual_gr, quarter_gr):
    if annual_gr > 0:
        annual_growth_rate = 'increased'
    elif annual_gr < 0:
        annual_growth_rate = 'decreased'
    else:
        annual_growth_rate = 'stayed the same'

    if quarter_gr > 0:
        quarterly_growth_rate = 'increased'
    elif quarter_gr < 0:
        quarterly_growth_rate = 'decreased'
    else:
        quarterly_growth_rate = 'stayed the same'
    
    gr_named_tuple = GrowthIncDec(annual_growth_rate=annual_growth_rate, quarterly_growth_rate=quarterly_growth_rate)
    
    return gr_named_tuple


myfunc = increase_decrease(5, -1)
myfunc.annual_growth_rate

output: 'increased'
```

A snippet of my main code is as follows to illustrate the use of the above function:

```
def get_comments(grp, some_dict: Dict[str, List[str]]):
    .......

    try:
        subdf = the dataframe
        annual_gr = subdf['Annual_Growth'].values[0]
        quarter_gr = subdf['Quarterly_Growth'].values[0]

        inc_dec_named_tup = increase_decrease(annual_gr, quarter_gr)
        
        inc_dec_annual_gr = inc_dec_named_tup.annual_growth_rate
        inc_dec_quarterly_gr = inc_dec_named_tup.quarterly_growth_rate

        comment = "The {} has {} by {:.1%} in {} {} compared to {} {}"\
                  .format(market, inc_dec_annual_gr, annual_gr, timeperiod, curr_date, timeperiod, prev_year)

        comments_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date','Comments'])
        
        # comments_df['Date'] = [curr_date]
        comments_df['Comments'] = [comment]

        return comments_df
    
    except (IndexError, KeyError) as e:
        # this is for all those nan values which is empty
        annual_gr = 0
        quarter_gr = 0
```

Comment: No real way  to make this simpler or more efficient as far as I know.

Comment: Can you show the sample data and desired output?